# How does this React example work?

Tags: reactjs

I'm currently trying to learn React, and maybe I'm just sleepy and missing something, but I need to ask:

In this code example(from React's "Getting Started" pages), why is "World" printed?
From what I can see, where this.props.name is passed, the function is looking for children, not picking up additional text input. At least that's how I interpret the docs re: React.createElement.

This code is "working as intended", printing "Hello World"...but can anyone tell me exactly *why* it works? I would expect to just see "Hello", and maybe a console error about "World" not being defined. To whoever answers, thank you in advance for your explanation. ;)

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
 displayName: 'Hello',
 render: function() {
  return React.createElement("div", null, "Hello ", this.props.name);
 }
});

ReactDOM.render(
 React.createElement(Hello, { name: "World"}),
 container
);
```

Comment: The object `{name: "World"}` in the render method is the definition of `this.props.name` that you set as a parameter when creating the component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `React.createElement` function takes the type of element to be created (if a string is passed it's an HTML element name, but it can also be a reference to a `ReactClass`), then a `props` object, then an undetermined number of children as the following arguments.

When you invoke

```
React.createElement(Hello, { name: "World"})
```

you are passing `Hello` as the React Class to be instantiated and an object `{ name: "World"}` as the `props`, which is then available as `this.props` in all the methods of `Hello`, including the `render` method.

Then the `Hello` element (class) calls `createElement` again:

```
React.createElement("div", null, "Hello ", this.props.name)
```

here, `"div"` is the type of HTML element to be created, `props` are null, and both `"Hello "` and `this.props.name` are children to be created, in this example simple strings, the first one being a literal string, the second one is a reference to a key in the `props` object passed above.

So what you have probably missed is that you can pass any number of arguments to the `createElement` method and all the arguments starting with the 3rd will be rendered as sibling elements.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see, inside the render function, there's an additional parameter passed into the `createElement` function.

First parameter is the component class which you would like to instantiate and second are the props. Here we have a `name` prop defined with a value of `"World"`.

Since the `Hello` component takes in the prop called `name`, it will render it out along with the `"Hello "` that the component is told to contain. It is a simple `div` element.

[Here you can see](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.createelement) the parameters defined and explained for the `createElement` function that React exposes.

Namely:

`React.createElement("div", null, "Hello ", this.props.name);`

Element Type - `div`
Props - `null`
Two children - `"Hello "` and `this.props.name` (which is `"World"`)